# Samples failing on increasing number of users and decreasing Ramp-up Period

Tags: jmeter

For Jmeter script, when I use

```
Number of Threads = 10
Ramp-up Period = 40
Loop Count = 1
```

Then 6 out of 40 samples failed.

When I increase the Ramp-up Period to 60 then all the samples pass.

For the failed requests, the response code returned is 522:

**Sampler result**

```
Thread Name: Liberty Insight 1-4
Sample Start: 2018-02-23 20:43:12 IST
Load time: 1
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 1
Size in bytes: 112
Sent bytes:584
Headers size in bytes: 112
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): 
Response code: 522
Response message: 

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 522 
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 23 Feb 2018 15:13:12 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

I am unable to figure out the reason for this type of behaviour.  Any pointers what could be issue for such type of behaviour?

Comment: Error 522 means server could not be reached at all... Simply speaking your server couldn't hold the load. Increasing ramp-up helped probably helped because you are doing 1 iteration (so some threads finished before others even started), so it doesn't really change the fact that server couldn't hold the load. Try more iterations with 60 ramp-up, and it will probably fail. Since you are using nginx, I'd check first if nginx is properly configured, e.g. https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose Ramp-up Period = 40 with 10 threads calls to server are about 4 transaction a second.

When you use [cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/signin?return_to=https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171906-Error-522-Connection-timed-out) services one of its feature is to prevent overload the server

> There are a few main causes of this:
>
> The origin server was too overloaded to respond.
>
> The origin web server has a firewall that is blocking our requests, or packets are being dropped within the host’s network.

Error 522:
[image]
<sub>(source: [cloudflare.com](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/201814387/error522.png))</sub>

If you need to load test your server use different route than cloudflare, Consult your IT for such option.

If not reduce transaction per second rate

> Ensure that the origin server isn’t overloaded. If it is, it could be dropping requests.